# void() issue - It doesn't print results

Tags: c++, program-entry-point, visual-studio-2015, void, cout

I am writing a program split in three different files:

1. 1) An header named `my.h`;
2. A source cpp file named `my.cpp`;
3. The main file named `use.cpp`;

Here their statements:

```
/* Header file my.h
Define global variable foo and functions print and print_foo
to print results out */

extern int foo;
void print_foo();
void print(int);
```

---

```
/* Source file my.cpp where are defined the two funcionts print_foo() and print()
and in where it is called the library std_lib_facilities.h */

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
#include "my.h"

void print_foo() {
    cout << "The value of foo is: " << foo << endl;
    return;
} 
void print(int i) {
    cout << "The value of i is: " << i << endl;
    return;
}
```

---

```
/ use.cpp : definisce il punto di ingresso dell'applicazione console.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "my.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int foo = 7;
    int& i = foo;
    i = 99;
    char cc = '0';

    while (cin >> cc) {
        switch (cc) {
        case '1':
            void print_foo();
            break;
        case '2':
            void print();
            break;
        default:
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

My main problem is that program compiles and run correctly but it doesn't print anything as I supposed.

How can I fix it?

Thank you!

Leo

Comment: I have solved the issue! I have tried to rewrite it all and test it with Code::blocks instead of Visual Studio and there it seemed cleaner the problem. Both don't accept extern int handling in that way so, once removed and declared in main scope, the program worked and ran.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call a function specifying return type is not required. Correct

```
void print_foo();    // This actually declares a function prototype
```

to

```
print_foo();
```

and

```
print(i);    // Pass i as argument
```

Comment: I am sorry was a my mistake post `void print_foo()` instead of `print_foo()` :)

Comment: Once removed `void` before calling the function, I get this kind of error and program does not compile anymore.. 
_LNK2019 riferimento al simbolo esterno "void __cdecl print_foo(void)" (?print_foo@@YAXXZ) non risolto nella funzione _wmain use H:\C++\Projects\use\use\use.obj_ 
and _LNK2019 riferimento al simbolo esterno "void __cdecl print(int)" (?print@@YAXH@Z) non risolto nella funzione _wmain use H:\C++\Projects\use\use\use.obj_.
@Shreevardhan it could just be a Visual Studio project type issue? I chose a Console Project Win32 as usual.

Answer (score 1):

Drop the `void` from `void print_foo();` and `void print();` in the `switch` blocks.

Currently you're just declaring a *function prototype*; not actually *calling* the function.

Your `extern int foo;` approach, while syntactically valid, can make your codebase harder to scale and maintain: consider passing the parameter explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Your code claims to *"Define global variable foo..." as follows...

```
extern int foo;
```

...but that just declares that some translation unit will actually define it (without the leading `extern` qualifier).  There's no actual variable in the code you've posted, which means your program shouldn't link unless some library you're using coincidentally has a `foo` symbol in it.

This shorter code condenses your problem:

```
#include <iostream>

extern int foo;

void f()
{
    std::cout << foo << '\n';
}

int main() {
    int foo = 7;
    f();
}
```

You can see the compiler error message [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/54adf91c3b4a5e0f), namely:

```
/tmp/ccZeGqgN.o: In function `f()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x6): undefined reference to `foo'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 0):

You would put in the main function

```
case '1':
    print_foo();
    break;
```

Notice I erased the word "void" in the case 1.  Because you don't redeclare the function there.  You just use it.

Comment: It isn't necessary to pass `foo` as a parameter (it is a good idea, though.)

Comment: Thanks, I changed my answer.